# VB6 Argument Not Optional

Tags: vb6

I'm having trouble with my code, i tried to google it but im failed fixing it. I hope someone can help me how to figure out what's wrong with my code. TIA

here is the Proc_9_6_4163C4

```
Public Sub Proc_9_6_4163C4(arg_C, arg_10, arg_14) '4163C4
          'Data Table: 40170C
          Dim var_120 As Variant
        loc_4161D8:   On Error GoTo loc_4163C2
        loc_4161E1:   var_98 = CVar(arg_C) 'Variant
        loc_4161EB:   var_A8 = CVar(arg_10) 'Variant
        loc_4161F5:   var_C8 = CVar(arg_14) 'Variant
        loc_41620A:   ReDim var_CC(0 To CLng(Len(var_A8)))
        loc_416225:   ReDim var_D0(0 To CLng(Len(var_C8)))
        loc_41623E:   For var_150 = 1 To Len(var_A8): var_E0 = var_150 'Variant
        loc_41626F:     var_CC(CLng(var_E0)) = CByte(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_A8, CLng(var_E0), 1))))
        loc_41627E:   Next var_150 'Variant
        loc_416293:   For var_184 = 1 To Len(var_C8): var_E0 = var_184 'Variant
        loc_4162C4:     var_D0(CLng(var_E0)) = CByte(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_C8, CLng(var_E0), 1))))
        loc_4162D3:   Next var_184 'Variant
        loc_4162DE:   var_F0 = 1 'Variant
        loc_4162E7:   var_100 = 1 'Variant
        loc_4162FA:   For var_1A4 = 1 To Len(var_98): var_E0 = var_1A4 'Variant
        loc_416350:     var_B8 = var_B8 & Chr(CLng(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_98, CLng(var_E0), 1))) Xor CInt(var_CC(CLng(var_F0))) Xor CInt(var_D0(CLng(var_100))))) 'Variant
        loc_41636C:     If (var_F0 = Len(var_A8)) Then
        loc_416374:       var_F0 = 0 'Variant
        loc_416378:     End If
        loc_416384:     If (var_100 = Len(var_C8)) Then
        loc_41638C:       var_100 = 0 'Variant
        loc_416390:     End If
        loc_416398:     var_120 = (var_F0 + 1)
        loc_41639C:     var_F0 = Len(var_C8) 'Variant
        loc_4163A8:     var_120 = (var_100 + 1)
        loc_4163AC:     var_100 = Len(var_C8) 'Variant
        loc_4163B3:   Next var_1A4 'Variant
        loc_4163BE:   var_88 = CStr(var_B8)
        loc_4163C2:   Exit Sub
        End Sub
```

and here is my code on my button click

```
        Private Sub Command1_Click()
          Dim var_C0 As Variant
          Dim var_FC As Variant
          Dim var_13C As String
          Dim var_10C As String
        var_88 = Replace("B5BD-BEBA-BBB9-B8B8-BD", "-", vbNullString, 1, -1, 0)
        var_88 = Proc_9_6_4163C4(var_88, CStr(Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HFE) & Chr(&HFD)))
        For var_EC = 1 To CInt(Len(var_88)): var_E2 = var_EC 'Integer
             If ((var_E2 Mod 4) = 0) Then
              var_13C = "-"
              var_E8 = CStr(CVar(var_E8) & Hex(CVar(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_88, CLng(var_E2), 1))))) & var_13C)
             Else
               var_E8 = CStr(CVar(var_E8) & Hex(CVar(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_88, CLng(var_E2), 1))))))
             End If
             Next var_EC 'Integer
        var_D0 = (Right(var_FC, 1) = var_10C) 'Variant

        Text1.Text = (CStr(IIf(var_D0, CVar(Asc(CStr(Mid(var_88, CLng(var_E2), 1)))), var_E8)))
        End Sub
```

i'm having trouble with this line. : `var_88 = Proc_9_6_4163C4(var_88, CStr(Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HFE) & Chr(&HFD)))`

i tried add some set on var_88 = Proc_9_6_4163C4(var_88, CStr(Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HFE) & Chr(&HFD)))

i put like this `set var_88 = Proc_9_6_4163C4(var_88, CStr(Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HFE) & Chr(&HFD)))`

but still i didn't get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

To call the procedure 3 arguments need to be passed while the call

```
var_88 = Proc_9_6_4163C4(var_88, CStr(Chr(&HFF) & Chr(&HFE) & Chr(&HFD)))
```

has only 2 arguments. Pass 1 more argument to the call.

Comment: The function takes `arg_C, arg_10, arg_14`. You are not providing anything for `arg_14`.